# Suppose that, for any given $\varepsilon>0,A\subseteq\Bbb R^2$ can be covered by a set $B$ with $\nu(B)<\varepsilon.$ Prove $\nu(A)=0.$

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, proof-writing

> Let $\nu(B)$ denote the Jordan measure of a bounded set $B\subseteq\Bbb R^2.$ Suppose that, for any given $\varepsilon>0,A\subseteq\Bbb R^2$ can be covered by a set $B$ with $\nu(B)<\varepsilon.$ Prove $\nu(A)=0.$

**My attempt:**

Let $\varepsilon>0,\space B\supseteq A$ s. t. $\nu(B)<\varepsilon$ and rectangle $R\supseteq B$ be arbitrary. Since $\nu(B)<\varepsilon,$ there is a subdivision $P$ of $R$ s. t. the corresponding upper Darboux sum $S_{\chi_B}(P)<\varepsilon$. Then

$$S_{\chi_B}(P)=\sum_{R_{ij}\in P\\R_{ij}\cap B\ne\emptyset}\nu(R_{ij}),$$ which means $B$ is covered by finitely many rectangles $R_{ij}$ of the overall area less than $\varepsilon,$ but $A\subseteq B\implies\chi_A\le\chi_B\implies S_{\chi_A}(P)\le S_{\chi_B}(P)<\varepsilon,$ so the same holds for $\varepsilon.$ Since $\varepsilon>0$ was arbitrary, $\nu(A)=0.$

Is my proof valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is correct in showing that the measure of $A$ should be $0$. Depending on how formal you want your answer to be, perhaps you also want to prove that the Jordan measure of $A$ exists as well. But this is very similar to what you have done: The *lower* Darboux sum of $A$ is again bounded by that of $B$, and as the supremum of lower Darboux sums for $B$ converge to $0$ by your argument, the same must hold for $A$. Thus, the inner measure and outer measure is equal, and we see that the Jordan measure exists.